# How to get a winforms CheckBox without text display its bottom edge?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, selectable

Im currently working on a WinForms Application with VS2013 (.NET 4.5, c#) .

I'd like to use a `CheckBox` without any `Label`. If I empty the `.Text` property the bottom edge of the `CheckBox` is not displayed anymore.
In order to bypass that effect i tried to use a single empty space ' ' as `Label`. Now the visual aspect is correct, but whenever the `CheckBox` is pressed the focus switches onto the `Label` and shows the user empty space.

Is there a more elegant way to handle that problem rather than using a custom control and set the selectable property to false?

```
    public class NonFocusCheckbox : CheckBox
    {
        public NonFocusCheckbox ()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        }
    }
```

Note: This solution works, but seems a bit odd to be required to do that

Comment: A normal CheckBox doesn't do that. There must be more to it to get that effect. Certain OS, certain theme of that OS, changed settings of the CheckBox like AutoSize, Appearance or FlatStyle?

Comment: Is the checkbox in a container of some sort, like a `TableLayoutPanel` that might be autosizing to a smaller size in the absence of the text?

Comment: Is it a standard .Net WinForms checkbox? Can you maybe post a screen shot of this effect?

Comment: I did indeed use `TableLayoutPanel` which was contributing to that effect. I was able to tracked it down to an issue with several nested Panels and their `AutoSize` properties that left the `Checkbox` without enough space to be fully displayed.
Thanks to you